# Problema con libreria ChilkatDotNet45.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de un tercero y al momento de compilar el proyecto obtengo el siguiente resultado.

```
    No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Error de código fuente: 

Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Seguimiento de la pila: 


[FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +196
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +45
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +172
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +692

[HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +659
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +188

Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.2046.0
```

Intenté descargar la version x86 de la página oficial https://www.chilkatsoft.com pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, de igual forma cambie el target de compilacion en Visual Studio

Estoy usando IIS Express el cual ya viene incorporado con Visual Studio (2017 Community) además de que también la estoy testeando en IIS de windows.

No sé qué más pueda ser.

Gracias.

Comment: Verificaste que la dll esta en la carpeta bin?

Comment: sí, en cada compilacion, las eliminaba para verficiar que se colocaran correctamente en la carpeta bin

Comment: Prueba a ver si tu Framework es mas alta que el framework que en el que se desarrollo esa libreria, si el tuyo es mas bajo no te funcionara.

Comment: Lo extraño es que en la pc del desarrollador original funcionó, la única forma de solucionarlo en mi pc, fue usar directamente IIS, ya que con el mismo Visual Studio me marcaba error, sigo sin entenderlo. Pero muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación debes tener instalado las C++ Redistribuible que te correspondan (C++ 2013 o 2012)

[Chilkat .NET Assemblies – Matching Visual Studio versions to .NET Framework Versions to VC++ Runtime Versions](http://cknotes.com/chilkat-net-assemblies-matching-visual-studio-versions-to-net-framework-versions-to-vc-runtime-versions/)

Por ejemplo, a mi en mi caso, tuve que instalar las C++ de 2012 para 32 bits ya que en mi proyecto hago uso de esta librería (también probé las del 2013 y continuaba el error):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Debes de instalar el Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2015.
De preferencia los dos el de 32 y el de 64 bits. (la misma plataforma que el componente que usas, pero no esta de más que ya los tengas)

Comment: Hola Miguel, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para guiar y solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal si pudieras indicar cómo  se instala lo que necesitas y por qué es necesario para resolver el problema. Personalmente, tengo curiosidad por saber por qué  dices de instalar las dos versiones y no sólo la que correspondería al SO particular. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Comment: Esta en la documentación de la librería.  No es que sea necesario instalar las dos, pero puede haber algo de confusión si por ejemplo, La aplicación se compilo en visual studio con Target "Any CPU" la aplicación en teoria va a correr bajo la plataforma destino que corresponda (32 o 64) pero si estamos en una maquina destino de 64 bits, y la aplicación de compilo con target "x86" pues va a correr como proceso de 32 bits aun estando en maquina de 64 bits. como que se me hace más rollo explicar todo es, si le soluciona instalando los dos :).

Comment: Esto es por que el Chilkat .NET assembly es un "mixed-mode".Proporciona una API administrada, pero el núcleo interno contiene código nativo

Comment: Diego Avila como puede decir que no resuelve la pregunta, si la pregunta esta mal formulada, como puede haber una mala respuesta; mi solución resuelve el problema y lo se por que lo he comprobado.

Comment: y Mi fuente es la pagina de instalacion de la libreria http://www.chilkatsoft.com/win32_Framework46.asp

Comment: @MiguelOscarGarcia Podrias por favor usar el boon [edit] y agregar toda la informacion que pussite en comentarios en la respuesta? inclui los links y todo lo necesario. Tambien, por favor, mira los enlaces que te paso Alvaro, que son [answer] y el [tour]